# Install python 2.7.11 on Ubuntu without compiling or replacing the pre-installed version

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, python, ppa

I'm using Ubuntu trusty which comes with `python 2.7.6` pre-installed. I need to install `2.7.11` in like `/usr/local/bin/python` without touching `/usr/bin/python` or compiling from source.

There are some links out there that says use [Felix Krull](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes-python2.7) repository:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes-python2.7
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python2.7 python2.7-dev
```

But the description of that repo clearly says:

> KEEP IN MIND that this PPA will replace a core system component (i.e.
>   Python 2.7)! While I've tried to minimise the risk of compatibility
>   issues, I don't take any responsibility for compatibility problems or
>   security issues with these packages.

Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python package would need to be recompiled to use the /usr/local prefix which would mean modifying the source package, you could download the source using apt-get source python2.7 and modifying the debian/rules file to compile with the /usr/local prefix but then apt would still see it as another newer replacement for python2.7 unless you renamed the package.

You would probably be better installing it from source using something like GNU stow so that it doesn't mess with your main installation https://www.gnu.org/software/stow/